# Custom blocks not rendering for anonymous users

Tags: blocks, updating

I recently deployed an update to Drupal 8.6.3 from 8.6.2 on our Drupal-specific managed web host (Pantheon).

Unfortunately, I noticed after the update that our site's footer was missing, but only for anonymous users. This footer is made of custom blocks placed in a footer region.

The footer is only missing for anonymous users. When you are logged in, the footer blocks appear properly. I've tried clearing the cache, running cron, clearing the cache again, etc. There are no errors in the watchdog logs that look like they would relate to this problem.

I've tried several, escalating troubleshooting steps to fix the error. Here they are, in more or less the order that I tried them:

- I created new custom blocks (using the "basic block" type) in the footer region. For these new blocks, I left them to display the title. The content of the new custom blocks were not rendered for anonymous users, but the title of the block was rendered. To further test, I edited the existing custom blocks in the footer region to display the title. The title displayed, but not the content. This tells me that Drupal is aware of the custom blocks in the region, but not rendering their content for anonymous users.
- I then added the built-in login block into the footer. This rendered properly for the anonymous user. This tells me the problem is limited to custom blocks
- I then added new custom blocks, and existing custom blocks, with titles, to the content region. I wanted to disprove the idea that there was a problem with the footer region. Like earlier, content was rendered for logged in users, but not for anonymous users. This tells me that the problem is with the content of custom blocks for anonymous users, regardless of the region they're placed in.

At this point, I decided that the problem probably just wasn't my particular config, and I did some googling to see if others had encountered this issue.

I found a number of issues regarding updating from 8.3.x to 8.5.x, and certain update hooks not running. We had been a little behind on updates, and had updated from 8.5.6 to 8.6.2 about a month ago, and then to 8.6.3 last night. So I didn't think these would apply to my situation, but I looked at their fixes and tried them if I could, anyway.

- [Basic Blocks are not visible for Anonymous users](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2962135)

When I looked at the databse, all of my block content and revision statuses already had the value `1`. For testing's sake, I did the update anyway. Still no blocks.

- [Core update from 8.3.x - 8.5.x Manual Process](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2951242#comment-12591871)

A commenter linked this from the first issue I looked at, so I checked it out. I didn't thing it applied, since we already had been running 8.5.6 for a while with no problem with our blocks. I didn't have these fields in my `block_content_revision` table, but when I added them, it didn't fix the problem.

- [Allow BaseFieldDefinition::setInitialValueFromField() to set a default value - this fixes issues with block_content_update_8400()](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2951242)

This seem to relate to schema update hooks for block revisions not having been run. For troubleshooting's sake, I set my block_content revision level to 0 to trigger a re-run of all the update hooks. This didn't resolve the issue.

In the issue queues that I looked at, there was also talk about the translation module. We don't have that enabled on our site.

So my site has a major issue, and it's kind of ruining my holiday. Any help would be appreciated!

**Edit** We rolled our site back to 8.6.2, restoring from a backup. custom blocks still not rendering. So, it seems that the core update was not causing the issue.

If anyone knows where to start adding debugging code into core to debug on local, please chime in.

**Edit 2** I've recreated the problem both on my home and work computers.

**Edit 3** As suggested in two separate comments, I've tried switching the theme to Bartik, and also disabling both the Page Cache modules (and clearing the cache afterwards). After creating and placing a brand new custom block (for a clean-ish test) with the title showing in two separate page sections, I still get the same behavior: for logged in users, I see the custom block title and content. But for the anonymous users, I see only the title of the block.

**Edit 5** At Kenorb's sugggestion, I looked to see if we were running any block permission modules. We are running `block_content_permission` and `block_region_permission` (however we are not running the `block_access` module). I looked into these, and they seem to only provide permissions for administration and editing of blocks. There was one permission that looked relevant-- `View restricted block content`. I enabled it for the anonymous user, but that didn't fix the problem. To test more robustly, I disabled both of those modules on my local, and again, no fix.

**Edit 6** regarding more suggestions: `updb` has been run. I tested this on a fresh local backport, `No database updates required.` Text filter format for blocks is `Full HTML`.

**Edit 7** re: Block visibility: there doesn't appear to be any restrictions on the problematic blocks. (Also, when I test by adding new custom blocks, I'm not adding any restrictions to them, and their title is displaying anyway). This is a screenshot:
[image]

**Edit 8** I also tried the patch, again on a new fresh backport, that kenorb suggsted:

```
$ git apply -vv 2997898-21.patch
Checking patch core/modules/block_content/block_content.install...
Applied patch core/modules/block_content/block_content.install cleanly.

$ drush @local.ccad updb
The following updates are pending:

block_content module :
  8601 -   Set 'reusable' field to '1' where it is NULL.

Do you wish to run all pending updates? (y/n): y
Performing block_content_update_8601
```

But sadly, again no luck : (

Comment: If something went wrong with updating the block database tables then the status page should display an error.

Comment: @4k4 I wouldn't disagree with you, but the issue queues regarding updates that didn't run didn't mention errors in the statue page.

Comment: I presume you already tried running an old backup from the day before the update to confirm if indeed it was the update that broke it.

Comment: So, if you've already rolled back and the problem persists, the core update can't be the problem, right? Could you rephrase the question?

Comment: If you switch to the Drupal default theme (Bartik) does the problem persist?

Comment: After all the tests you did, the next step i would test is :


Uninstall "Internal Dynamic Page Cache" and "Internal Page Cache" modules then rebuilding the site cache (drush cr)

Comment: @NoSssweat  I tried both of your suggestions (both separately and together) and I got the same behavior. See latest edit.

Comment: Are you using [Block Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/block_access) module or similar with some restricting permission access to view blocks?

Comment: Can you confirm, that you run db updates (`drush updb`)?

Comment: @user1359 Another shot into the blue: Have you tried disabling BigPipe module?

Comment: Please test the patch from: [Custom blocks are no longer displayed and no longer appear in the custom block library](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2997898), if that's the case.

Comment: What kind of format filter do you use for your block? Is it _Full HTML_ or _PHP_?

Comment: @Hudri We don't have BigPipe running.

Comment: Related Drupal issue: [Losing custom block library in sql database when clearing cache](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3015178).

Comment: Edit your block and check _Block visibility setting tab_, whether the block should be visible for all roles. If you don't see the tab, check: [Block visibility setting tab for Roles not showing](https://www.drupal.org/node/2952962).

Comment: @kenorb as regards `block_access`, please see edit #5. I checked and no fix : (

Comment: @kenorb `updb`, yes, just tested now on fresh local backport, `no updates required.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So it turns out that I misconfigured permissions on the body field of my basic block block type. I had meant to restrict permissions for it on another block type. Unfortunately, I didn't notice this when I first rolled out the configuration export to production.

*Edit* thanks to everyone who commented with suggestions. It feels good to know that people were trying to lend a hand and I wasn't alone in trying to figure this out.